# How can I copy sequences from one schema to another in Postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql, session, sequence, limesurvey

The objective is to figure out how to do this after copying tables from a schema, `schema 1`, to a new schema, `schema 2`, using the following method

```sql
create table if not exists {schema 2}.{lime_table} (like {schema 1}.{lime_table} including all);

insert into {schema 2}.{lime_table} (select * from {schema 1}.{lime_table});
```

Copying tables between schemas with this method leaves sequences in `schema 2` pointing to the sequences in `schema 1`. To remove dependencies/coupling with `schema 1`, I created identical sequences in `schema 2` with a script that utilized a template like

```sql
create sequence
    if not exists {schema_2_dot_sequence_name}
    increment by 1
    minvalue 1
    maxvalue 2147483647
    start {start_with} -- taken from `schema 1`.sequence.last_val
    cache 1
    no cycle
    owned by {schema_2_dot_table_dot_id_field_name}
;
```

and then altered the id columns in `schema 2` using

```sql
alter table {schema_2_dot_table}
    alter column {id_field_name}
        set default nextval({schema_2_dot_sequence}::regclass)
```

After making these database changes, I pointed my application (Limesurvey) to `schema 2`.

Now when trying to insert records to `schema 2`, the error `currval of sequence "<sequence_name>" is not yet defined in this session` is thrown. If I point my app back to `schema 1` (creating a new database connection/session), I do not get this error, so it leads me to think that the sequence "migration" I did is wrong. The app is using the php function [lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.PDO-lastInsertId.php).

**Update:** I did a `pg_dump` and did not find any instances of `schema 1` in the output, so maybe the migration I did works and there is a config in the app somewhere pointing to the `schema 1`...

Comment: [depending on the Postgres version] `CREATE table xxx.aaa AS SELECT * FROM yyy.bbb INCLUDING ALL;` (see the manual for details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the stack trace, I found references to `schema 1` being made. For example, `C:\...\CDbCommandBuilder.php(62): CDbConnection->getLastInsertID("public.lime_user_groups_ugid_seq")`, where `public` is `schema 1`. And because `schema 1` didn't appear in the `pg_dump`, I knew it must've been an issue with the app configs. I found there were a few hidden `schema 1` strings to change in the codebase with the help of https://forums.limesurvey.org/forum/installation-a-update-issues/111790-installation-on-a-different-schema. This means the method I used to migrate/copy tables and their sequences from one schema to another works.

**Update:** The problem was in the app configs. Our database uses a pgpool connection with two pg servers. Connecting to the pool created the error. It went away after connected directly to the main/master pg server.